Monitor on Headless: Ubuntu 24.04 Server + Xubuntu-core
I have a device running Ubuntu 24.04 Server, on which I later installed Xubuntu-core because it is needed for some programs.
If I boot the device with a monitor attached, everything works fine. I can unplug the monitor and later reattach it, and everything continues to work as expected. However, if I boot the device without a monitor attached and later connect one, it refuses to display anything. Do note that, upon shutdown, the system does display all the verbosity on the monitor.
The only way I've found to get the display working in this scenario is to reboot the system with the monitor attached. I have already tried changing the NVIDIA drivers and using different ports and monitors, but nothing seems to resolve the issue.
In my application, it is not always possible to have the monitor attached upon boot.
How can I configure the system to start without a screen attached and still be able to attach a monitor later and have it work?
